# Using Node.js, how can I check whether a domain name is registered?

Tags: javascript, dns, node.js, whois

I'm building a simple webapp to teach myself node.js, and in it I need to check whether a certain domain name specified by the user is registered. I'm not really sure how to go about this and I'd appreciate it if anybody could enlighten me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this article by Matt Brubeck:

http://limpet.net/mbrubeck/2010/01/13/si-unit-domains-node-js.html

There is a Node.js script that does exactly that.

Comment: [Returns false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76807811/how-to-reliably-and-effectively-check-domain-availability-in-batch-with-node-js).

Answer (score 3):

I did not found the correct answer for this question. My solution is over here

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/whois
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is to use the `dns` module to do a `resolve`, and if nothing is returned or an error is thrown it's not registered yet.

https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html

Comment: It is wrong to use DNS queries for this need. A domain name can be registered without being delegated, for multiple legit reasons, so you will have false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Run something like this:

```
//loads the Node core DNS module
var dns = require ( 'dns' )

function checkAvailable( url ) {
  //uses the core modules to run an IPv4 resolver that returns 'err' on error
  dns.resolve4( url, function (err, addresses) {
    if (err) console.log (url + " is possibly available : " + err)
  })
}
// calls the function of a given url        
checkAvailable( "ohwellhaithar.com" )
```

Comment: It is wrong to use DNS queries for this need. A domain name can be registered without being delegated, for multiple legit reasons, so you will have false positives.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek what do you suggest as being a more effective way to do the DNS check? I did something in line with EhvuTov's suggestion here that can now also be used as an API: https://www.clay.run/services/nicoslepicos/is-domain-name-available/code

To use as an API just hit :

POST https://exec.clay.run/nicoslepicos/is-domain-name-available with the domain name parameter in the POST body (or use the Clay SDK if you're in node).

Comment: To do a domain availability/registered check (not a DNS check), either use the `whois` protocol, or specific registry service for checking domain availability (depends on the TLD) or use one registrar API that has the TLDs you need, since the registrars, through EPP typically, can do realtime availability checks at the registry. Also in above answer, *url* and *domain name* are not interchangeable, what is handled above are domain names, not URLs.

Comment: 2022-12-17 I got `35 vulnerabilities (3 low, 8 moderate, 21 high, 3 critical)` after install this package (Nodejs 16 macOS), hmm