# How to reliably and effectively check domain availability in batch with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, dns

I tried using [the DNSimple API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpapEXe2-Tc) in Node.js:

```
const { DNSimple } = require("dnsimple");
const fs = require('fs')

require('dotenv').config()

const client = new DNSimple({
  accessToken: process.env.DNSIMPLE_API_TOKEN,
  // baseUrl: "https://api.sandbox.dnsimple.com",
});

start()

// Check for domain availability
async function start() {
  const words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  const matches = []

  const tlds = ['link', 'site', 'host', 'surf']

  for (const tld of tlds) {
    for (const word of words) {
      const domain = `${word}.${tld}`
      const { data: availability } = await client.registrar.checkDomain(accountId, domain)
      // const res = await fetch(`https://api.dnsimple.com/v2/142669/registrar/domains/${domain}/check`, {
      //   headers: {
      //     Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.DNSIMPLE_API_TOKEN}`
      //   }
      // })
      // const json = await res.json()
      // console.log(json)
      if (availability.available) {
        console.log(domain)
        matches.push(domain)
        fs.writeFileSync('tmp/domains.csv', matches.join('\n'))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, even with an API Token and being registered and all that, I only am getting ~30 "check domain" requests per hour rate limit. How can I check a few thousand domains efficiently, in Node.js?

My specific problem is, I have been using [tld-list.com](https://tld-list.com/) to check domain availability *by hand* "in bulk", but it only allows you to check all domains like `foo.*`, not `*.<sometld>`, I want to check a few thousand keywords to see if a `.com` or `.link` tld exist for that keyword. How can I do this effectively in Node.js (or even a bash script)?

If it's not possible, why is it not possible? How are sites like `tld-list.com` polling the domain availability for `foo.*` but are unable to do `*.<tld>`? If it is possible, where should I be looking / or what module could I dig into in Node.js to facilitate this?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034048/using-node-js-how-can-i-check-whether-a-domain-name-is-registered), this script should work:

```
const dns = require("dns")
const fs = require('fs')

start()

async function check(domain) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    dns.resolve4(domain, function (e) {
      if (!e || e.errno == dns.NXDOMAIN) res(domain);
      return rej(e)
    });
  });
}

// Check for domain availability
async function start() {
  const words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  const matches = []

  const tlds = ['link', 'site', 'host', 'surf']

  for (const tld of tlds) {
    for (const word of words) {
      const domain = `${word}.${tld}`

      try {
        await check(domain)
        console.log(domain)
        matches.push(domain)
        fs.writeFileSync('tmp/domains.csv', matches.join('\n'))
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it gives false positives... Any ideas?

If there is a service that offers unrestricted API access, that would be a good answer, or even something with a rate limit of a few thousand per hour would suffice. But knowing how to reliably check without a rate limit would be even better (or why it's not possible).

Even checking with `whois` package, it gives false positives:

```
async function check2(domain) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    whois.lookup(domain, { timeout: 2000 }, (err, data) => {
      if (data) {
        if (data.match(/is available for registration/)) {
          return res()
        }
        return rej(new Error('Domain taken'))
      } else {
        if (err.message.match(/timeout/)) {
          return rej(new Error('Unknown'))
        }
        res()
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: You can always do a DNS NS record check first, then a registrar check as a fallback. DNS tests are cheap and not usually that rate limited, but if they are you can stand up your own DNS server super easily.

Comment: @tadman can you show how to do that por favor? Or explain in more detail with some pseudocode?

Comment: Node has a very capable [DNS resolver library](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html) that can get the records for you. In practice I've found about 80% of registered domains have DNS, the rest are somehow ghost domains, registered but with zero presence, not even an SOA record.

Comment: @tadman, I just tried using Node.js's dns library, but it gives false positives.... Any ideas?

Comment: Test that your provider isn't being a jerk and providing "page not found" entries for everything, as in `dig NS thisdomainisnotreal.com` comes back with no records versus `dig NS real.com` which is.